# Unique username value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to keep only unique values at username (field inside table professionals, using MySql at the moment).

I got a edit profile page where the user can change his username and other values.

EXAMPLE:

---

Actual info (not edited):

```
Name: John;
Tel: 1234567890;
Username: john;
Password:****;
```

New info (edited):

```
Name: Jonathan;
Tel: 1234567890;
Username: john;
Password:****;
```

---

As you can see the user only changed the name, so I'm inserting all data again in database, but if I verify the username of course it says there is already one at DB.
I need some kind of solution for this, without changing a lot the whole code.
Thanks

Comment: An ID auto increment column might help...

Comment: Add unique constraint on the field.

Comment: You could have actually added the code snippet. In that way, people who would like to help could easily point changes.

Comment: What you have tried? show your code.

Comment: Given no code or db schema, makes your question next to impossible to answer. *Keep on Googling.*

Comment: Have you read about SQL's [`UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) (instead of `INSERT`)?

Comment: @Chris I'm using UPDATE, but isn't it a form of inserting data? I didn't say I was using INSERT
Thanks

Comment: Really thanks for the answer @Jeff ! I wasn't thinking about the user ID, I can just make a query like this: SELECT * FROM professionals WHERE username = "teste" AND id_professional != 3 and after that just verify if there are rows or not.

Answer (score 0):

What is the need for inserting the whole data once again in the table.  Try updating the table.

```
 UPDATE table_name SET column1=value1,column2=value2,... WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

And in your case like

```
UPDATE table_name SET Name='Jonathan' where Username = 'john'
```

Answer (score 0):

Really thanks for the answer @Jeff ! I wasn't thinking about the user ID, I can just make a query like this: SELECT * FROM professionals WHERE username = "test" AND id_professional != 3 and after that just verify if there are rows or not.